# Using Python to import CSV from remote machine into Azure SQL Server

Tags: python, sql-server, csv, sql-insert

I am trying to find a way to import a CSV file into Azure SQL Server from a remote machine using Python. I wrote a script to GET data from a third-party API and then flatten JSON into a CSV file.  It works great. Now, I'm trying to improve the script to import that CSV into Azure SQL Server so that I don't have to manually upload the file using the Import Flat File tool.

```
with pyodbc.connect(f'''DRIVER={dw_driver};SERVER={dw_server};PORT={dw_port};DATABASE={dw_database};UID={dw_user};PWD={dw_password}''') as dw_connection:

    with dw_connection.cursor() as dw_curs:

        with open(out_file, 'r') as csv_file:
            for row in csv_file:
                dw_curs.execute('insert into DataOperations.StageTable (Id, CustomerName, CustomerEmail, CustomerOrganization, AssistedSalesPerson) values (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)', row)
```

This code returns the following error:

> ProgrammingError: ('The SQL contains 0 parameter markers, but 1
>   parameters were supplied', 'HY000')

When I print the generated SQL statement, it looks this:

```
insert into DataOperations.StageTable (Id, CustomerName, CustomerEmail, CustomerOrganization, AssistedSalesPerson) values (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s) 12345678|Test Name|testemail@test.com| Test Company |
```

Can anyone help me modify this script into a working SQL insert statement? I've trawled other similar questions on here but most recommend usin `BULK INSERT` which will not work because this file is not available on the database server.

Comment: the last value from rows is NULL  or empty??

Comment: Yeah, it's a null/empty value. Any value except for Id can be null.

Comment: then in your insert is not necessary set column Id

Comment: Id is not auto-incrementing, it's just a non-null integer field. It needs to be part of the insert.

Answer (score 0):

The `csv.reader()` function must be used to create an object that can be used to iterate over lines in the target CSV file. The SQL parameters within the values() statement must use `?` instead of `%s` to be valid syntax. The solution below is confirmed as working.

```
with pyodbc.connect(f'''DRIVER={dw_driver};SERVER={dw_server};PORT={dw_port};DATABASE={dw_database};UID={dw_user};PWD={dw_password}''') as dw_connection:

    with dw_connection.cursor() as dw_curs:

        with open(out_file, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as csv_file:
            next(csv_file, None)  # skip the header row
            reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter='|')
            for row in reader:
                dw_curs.execute('insert into DataOperations.StageTable (Id, CustomerName, CustomerEmail, CustomerOrganization, AssistedSalesPerson) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)', row)
```